# For the factorising technique "adding zero" how am I supposed to know what "zero" to add?

Tags: factoring

Let be $$x^4 - x^2 - 2x -1$$

I used photomath to see that $x^3$ needs to be added and subtracted. How would I have been able to figure this out myself?

Answer (score 2):

It's $$x^4-(x+1)^2=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x+1).$$

Comment: thanks! this is a faster way. But let's say I wasn't able to see this straight away haha
Another example is x^4 + 1 which HAS to be add zero (right?!)

Comment: @basura Any polynomial of fourth degree with real coefficients we can write as different of squares.

Comment: right. do polynomials of different degrees have similar rules? ie what bout 3rd, 5th, 6th etc. Or is this limited to 4th degree; if so is there a reason? And what is the process of writing a polynomial of 4th degree as a diff of 3 sqaures

Comment: @basura What is it difference of three squares? :)

Comment: oops haha i mean diff of sqaures